# "have you seen it" or "did you see it"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

In the following sentence:

> I was carrying a new leather bag; **have you seen it**?

Shouldn't the author have said:

> I was carrying a new leather bag; **did you see it?**

In the sense that she is looking for it.

If the present perfect is correct, kindly; explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Present Perfect Simple:

> The time of the action that is described is **before now**, but **not specified**, and **we are often more interested in the result** than in the action itself. [[Source]](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/#:%7E:text=The%20present%20perfect%20is%20used,than%20in%20the%20action%20itself.)

From your example's context, someone is looking for her bag, so she cares more about whether the other person has seen it before, rather than the specific time they may have seen it. Additionally, since she wants to find her bag, she is more interested in the result of the other person's action - If the other person has seen her bag, she may be able to get information that will help her find it.